# Equation formatting: spacing between characters

Tags: spacing, equations, formatting

I have the following variable: `$\omega_{fo}$` which gives [;\omega_{fo};] . The problem with the output is that there is a quite big separation between the letters `f` and `o`.

Is there a way to make them come closer?

NB: the `fo` stands for forcing---this is why it's in italic (normal math mode) and not written upright.

Thanks a lot...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's recommended to use **amsmath** if you do serious mathematical typesetting.

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
...
$\omega_{\textit{fo}}$
```

With **amsmath** it's not necessary to specify the text size.

Comment: Thanks. Yes I use amsmath. Your output seems to have a bigger size for `fo` than the one in the solution fro @Harrold. Is this the correct way? 1 vote up.

Comment: In my test the size is correct and it's exactly the same as with `\scriptsize`.

Comment: Not really. `\omega_{\mathit{fo}}` and `\omega_{\textit{\scriptsize fo}}` gives the same output but not `\omega_{\textit{fo}}`.

Comment: If you load **amsmath** the result is the same; it isn't without that package.

Comment: Thanks. Now I see that `\omega_{\textit{\scriptsize fo}}` gives slightly smaller `fo`. So I will go for one of the remaining two. And I am choosing to accept your answer instead.

Answer (score 2):

```
$\omega_{\textit{\scriptsize fo}}$
```

It is the first one.

[image: The first one.]

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility—without switching to text mode—is:

```
$\omega_{\mathit{fo}}$
```

However, as the subscript "fo" is an abbreviation rather than the name of a variable I would recommend to use a roman font for it:

```
$\omega_{\mathrm{fo}}$
```

See, for instance, http://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb18-1/tb54becc.pdf.

Comment: Thanks. But `forcing` is not an object. This means that we cannot have it upright. This is a common mistake. But if I had say `table`, then I would have written say `\omega_{\mathrm{tab}}`, with `tab` referring to table. 1 vote up.